path is not defined in Electron build
I have Electron app based on https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate. I installed node js library and for it to work used such code in my webpack.config.base.ts:

new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
process: 'process/browser', // Automatically polyfills process
}),

in plugins section. But when I package and run executable file. I get error:

(node:41937) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
at validateString (node:internal/validators:163:11)
at Object.join (node:path:1172:7)
at createWindow


If you need to polyfill anything from Node.js then you are not following Electron security docs. You should not use Node.js on the renderer process.
